# Connecting Visual Basic to C# WCF

Tags: c#, vb.net, wcf

I have some services built with C# WCF and this service is self-hosted. My main application is built with visual basic and with the .NET Framework. I have a webform in `.aspx.vb` and I want to connect to the services in C# WCF.

This is what I have done:

- Right-click to add service reference.
- Visual Basic created a `App_WebReferences` folder with `ServiceReference1` folder. Inside the `ServiceReference1` folder, it contains the `Reference.svcmap`.
- Inside the `Reference.svcmap`, there are more files with the extensions `.svcinfo`, `.disco`, `.wsdl`, `.xsd`.

How do I call the WCF operation contracts from my Visual Basic .aspx.vb web form?

Answer (score 1):

The difference in the language of the server and client generally does not have a big impact. Because you send a request with parameters to the service to process, it will only return you a result.

For example:

I have a WCF service in C#:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }
    }
```

Client code:

```
  Module Module1
    
        Sub Main()
            Dim client As Service1Client = New Service1Client()
            Dim result As String = client.GetData(1)
            Console.WriteLine(result)
            Console.ReadLine()
        End Sub

End Module
```

Output:
[image]